# Parsing a website

Tags: python, parsing, error-handling, logging, web-scraping

Following is the code I wrote to download the information of different items in a page.

I have one main website which has links to different items. I parse this main page to get the list. This is handled by the `Items` class.

I also parse these each of the links in the list using the `Item` class.

I have implemented a `Handler` class which is the base class for both of these classes.

```
class Handler:

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.property = {}
        self.homeDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.parser = self.getParser()
        self.name = self.getTitle()
        self.setupFolder()

    def updateName(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def setupFolder(self):
        dataDir = os.path.join(self.homeDir, self.name)
        if not os.path.exists(dataDir):
            os.makedirs(dataDir)


    def getTitle(self):
        return "".join(char 
            for char in self.parser.title.string 
            if char.isalnum() or char == " ")


    def getFilePath(self):
        return os.path.join(self.homeDir, self.name)

    def getRequest(self, url):
        return urllib.urlopen(url).read()

    def getParser(self):
        parser = BeautifulSoup(self.getRequest(self.url))
        return parser

    def saveProperty(self, key, value):
        self.property[key] = value

    def writeProperty(self):
        fileName = self.getTitle() + ".property"
        with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
            f.write("\n".join(
                key + ":" + self.property[key] 
                for key in self.property))






class Items(Handler, object):

    def __init__(self, url, category) :

        super(Items, self).__init__(url)
        self.category = category
        self.updateName(category)

    def extractContents(self):
        self.parser = self.getParser()
        contents = self.parser.find("ul",{"class" : "galerie"}).findAll('li')
        print len(contents)
        return contents

    def downloadContents(self):
        for content in  self.extractContents():
            for elements in content.find('a'):
                for element in elements.findAll('dl'):
                    print element.text # I am just printing the contents
            print "==============================="



class Item(Handler, object):

    def __init__(self, url):

        super(Item, self).__init__(url)
        self.url = url
        self.homeDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.parser = self.getParser()
        self.name = self.getTitle()
        setupFolder()


    def write(self):
        pass
```

I'd appreciate any and all comments - correctness, style, best practices, logging, error handling.

Comment: As far as styling is concerned, I would suggest you go through. https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Naming#Naming. function_name are usually snake cased in python. Then maybe it's a bit Java-ish with get and set methods. For the rest I which this would be in github to have that cool feature of commenting directly in the code.

Comment: @jackdbernier Python has an official style guide, PEP8.

Comment: Thanks @EthanBierlein. I know about PEP8 and use it. Most of (if not all) the content on google-styleguide for python is from PEP8. The only reason I usually fallback to it is because they have stye guides for almost every languages. Also google-styleguide involve a lot of good common sense and is according to me less strict. Because really who likes to be PEP8'ed in a code review? And the very first python rule of the google-styleguide is to use pylint. Because code reviews need to go beyond PEP8 and let the style be judged by a machine.

Answer (score 2):

The general style for naming in Python is `snake_case` for functions and variables, and `PascalCase` for classes. You should also have two blank lines between top-level functions/classes/code blocks, not, an arbitrary amount. You have a few other style violations. To fix these, visit [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style guide.

Secondly, it looks like you're using Python 2.x. If you're using Python 2.x, you need to have classes explicitly inherit from `object`. For example: `class MyClass(object):`, not `class MyClass:`. If you are using Python 3.x, then you can use the second example.

Finally, you can use string multiplication to print many characters. For example, the line `print "==============================="` can be shortened to `print "=" * 31.